# @ORM\OneToMany Is retrieving the virtual deleted entries

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have a relation in Doctrine2 @ORM\OneToMany, suposing that i have table **school** and student, in the entity school i have the @ORM\OneToMany column **students**,
and i also have a **virtual deletion** column **deleted_at**, so every student that has the **deleted_at different of null** is a deleted student that is supposed **not to appear** in the column @ORM\OneToMany **$students**. How can i make this **filter**?

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Oceano\Entities\Student",
 *      mappedBy="cartCore",
 *      cascade={"all"}
 * )
 */
private $students;
```

So, when i call for school students, **it is retrieving also the deleted ones.**

```
$schoolObj->getStudents();
```

Any Solution using annotation or some clean change?

Answer (score 0):

You practically described Laravel's [soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting) feature. So, if you use it, you do not need to do anything and soft deleted students will not appear. You just need to add `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait to the `Student` model.

If you're using some own functionality, create a local scope in the `Student` model:

```
public function scopeNotDeleted($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
}
```

And use it:

```
Student::notDeleted()->get();
```

Or:

```
$school->students()->notDeleted()->get();
```

Comment: It works when i am calling something like this, $studet->findBy();

Comment: But it does not work, when i call something like this: $school->getStudents(); using the annotation @ORM\OneToMany, in $students field. :(

Comment: @AlbertAbdonor I'm sorry, I assumed you're using Eloquent since you're using Laravel. My solution is for Eloquent only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Criteria`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/1.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Criteria.html) filter class in your entity to students collection which are not deleted

```
protected getStudents() { 
    $criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
                ->where(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()->eq('deleted_at', null));
 return $this->students->matching($criteria);
}
```

To get deleted students you could write it like

```
protected getDeletedStudents() { 
    $criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
                ->where(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()->neq('deleted_at', null));
 return $this->students->matching($criteria);
}
```

[How filter data inside entity object in Symfony 2 and Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838216/how-filter-data-inside-entity-object-in-symfony-2-and-doctrine/31838947#31838947)

Comment: I would like something in annotations of doctrine2

Comment: @AlbertAbdonor AFAIK you can't do this directly via annotations or write and register your custom annotation for this purpose may some third party package is available for in bundled doctrine this isn't a default part

Comment: yep, i got the same conclusion. :(

Comment: @AlbertAbdonor Basically annotations are meant for mappings mostly for filtering you have to play around your entity and its gettter setters

Comment: yep. indeed! :)