# Is it possible to do joins in Doctrine with the Criteria functionality?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, criteria, dql

```
public function findActiveEvents($start, $end)
{
    $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(
           $expr->andX($expr->gte('start', $start), $expr->lte('end', $end)
    ));

    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

So let's say my event entity has a category and category has many events, how would I filter these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get collection of inactive events on category object you could use criteria class

```
class Category{
    protected $events; // (oneToMany)
    // ...
    protected getEvents() { // default method
        return $this->events;
    }
    protected getActiveEvents() { 
        $expr = Criteria::expr();
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        $criteria->where(
               $expr->andX($expr->gte('start', $start), $expr->lte('end', $end)
        ));
        return $this->events->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

[How filter data inside entity object in Symfony 2 and Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838216/how-filter-data-inside-entity-object-in-symfony-2-and-doctrine/31838947#31838947)