# Doctrine getting relational entites by status flag

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 3 tables `users`, `groups`, `group_users` (holds relation between group and user)

The table of `group_users` includes the following columns

```sql
-- (is_active 0: not active, 1: active)

| id | user_id | group_id | is_active |
| 1  |     1   |    1     |    1      |
| 2  |     1   |    2     |    0      |
```

In entity of `Group` I have a relational column like the following that gets group users using the relation in `group_users` table

```php
   /*
    * @ORM\Entity()
    * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
    */
   class Group{
     ...
    /**
     * @var Collection|GroupUser[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Group\Domain\Entity\GroupUser")
     */
    private $group_users;
```

In entity of `Group` I want to get group users but only ones that are active. In normal condition the relation above gets all related entities.

If I need to give an example, according to above records in `group_users` table, when I call variable like `$this->group_users` I want to see that only first record is listed

```sql
| id | user_id | group_id | is_active |
| 1  |     1   |    1     |    1      |
```

not this

```sql
| id | user_id | group_id | is_active |
| 2  |     1   |    2     |    0      |
```

Do you have any idea what's the best way to handle this problem, thanks.

Note: I don't want to physically delete any record.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18655514/231316

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new getter in `Group` entity which will filter out the related group users as per your criteria

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;


class Group{

    //...

    protected getActiveGroupUsers() { 
            $criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
                        ->where(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()->eq("is_active", 1));
         return $this->group_users->matching($criteria);
    }

}
```

And when you query a group you can get the related active group users as

```
$group = $em->getRepository("...\Group")->find($id);
$group->getActiveGroupUsers();
```

[**How filter data inside entity object in Symfony 2 and Doctrine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838216/how-filter-data-inside-entity-object-in-symfony-2-and-doctrine/31838947#31838947)